# Как удалить элемент NaN из массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив с элементами, которые функция должна удалять из входного массива, все удаляется, кроме `NaN`, знаю что это особенный и ни на кого не похожий тип данный, не равный даже самому себе, но легче от этого не становится. Как все-таки удалить его из массива? Ниже функция и пример ее вызова:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.\
  var tmp = [false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN];
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (tmp.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}


console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте строгое сравнение с самим собой:
`v !== v` принимает значение `true` только для `NaN`. [Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter( function(v){return !(v !== v);});
}

console.log( bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
//  [false, null, 0, undefined, ""]
```

**Upd**. как верно заметил @Grundy, приведённый выше фрагмент не решает задачу и не пригоден для копирования. Поэтому, спустя год+, переиздание. Версия исправленная и дополненная:

```js
function bouncer2(arr) {
  var outlaws = [false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN]
    , i = outlaws.length - 1
    , hasNaN = false
  ;
  
  for( i = 0; i < outlaws.length; i++)
    if( outlaws[i] !== outlaws[i]) {
      hasNaN = true;
      break;
    }
  ;

  i = 0;  
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if(
      !!~outlaws.indexOf( arr[i])  
      ||
      (hasNaN  &&  arr[i] !== arr[i])
    ) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer2([false, 'test', null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
// ["test"]
```

Comment: забавно, проблема в вопросе в том, что удалялось все кроме NaN, а в ответе решение для удаления _только_ NaN, хотя должно было удалиться все

Answer (score 3):

В плане удаления `NaN` ответ уже дан, но с учетом того, какая функция написана в вопросе, я бы ее изменил на:

```
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(val){
        return !!val
    });
}
```

Т.е. все значения в `tmp` - все, что может дать `false` при привидении к `Boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
...
if (tmp.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1 || typeof arr[i] == 'number' && isNaN(arr[i])) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вместо [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) стоит использовать [.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), в этой функции учтена особенность `NaN`, поэтому для него она тоже вернет `true`

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.\
  var tmp = [false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN];
  var i = 0;
  while (i < arr.length) {
    if (tmp.includes(arr[i])) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}


console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```